# stop processing .el file if emacs <= 22

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to build a small emacs plugin that talks to an HTTP API. Unfortunately the `url-retrieve` function had a different signature in emacs <= 22. I do not particularly want to support these older versions but I also do not want to break users' emacs installations by generating exceptions. Is it possible for me to abort the processing of an elisp source file if emacs is below a certain minimum version?

(Any pointers to best practices on building elisp packages that work across different versions of emacs would be much appreciated - I'm very much an elisp beginner.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to stop loading a file.  You could have a small lisp file that works with all versions and does nothing but selectively load other files depending on the Emacs version.

```
(if (<= emacs-major-version 22)
    (require 'foo-22)
  (require 'foo-23+))
```

There's also `emacs-minor-version` (also an int) and `emacs-version` (a string).

But you should probably just error out if the library doesn't work in old versions.  Whatever uses it will break eventually, so you might as well fail early and loudly.

Probably better would be to define a wrapper around `url-retrieve` that you can use for either version:

```
(defun foo-url-retrieve (url callback &optional cbargs silent inhibit-cookies)
  "Wrapper for `url-retrieve'."
  (if (<= emacs-major-version 22)
      (url-retrieve url callback cbargs)
    (url-retrieve url callback cbargs silent inhibit-cookies)))
```

You can even get fancy and try to emulate the way `url-retrieve` works in 23+. 
 But I sort of agree about not caring about versions as old as 22.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Emacs version](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Version-Info.html):

```
(when (>= 22 emacs-major-version)
  (error "Emacs version %d is not supported" emacs-major-version))
```

Note that v22 has been obsoleted by v23 almost 8 years ago. I doubt that many people are still using it... oops... take it back... Mac OS X Sierra comes with 22.1. ;-)